# How to pass jthread stop_token to functor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I'm trying to work with the new jthreads and have started a `std::jthread` where the operator() does get called, but I am unable to get it to stop. I want to create the thread by calling it as a function object.

```
my_thrd = std::make_shared<std::jthread>(&Test::operator(), &test);
```

If `operater()` of my Test class is written as the following, it compiles:

```
void Test::operator()()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    
    while (!token.stop_requested()) {
        std::cout << "Working ...\n" << std::flush;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    }   
    
    close_connection();
}
```

But since it wasn't stopping, I thought I needed to somehow pass `std::stop_token` to `class Test`, like so.

```
void Test::operator()(std::stop_token token) { ... }
```

But this doesn't compile. I did change the header as well.

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/thread: In instantiation of ‘static std::thread std::jthread::_S_create(std::stop_source&, _Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Test::*)(std::stop_token); _Args = {Test*}]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/thread:450:28:   required from ‘std::jthread::jthread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Test::*)(std::stop_token); _Args = {Test*};  = void]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/bits/stl_construct.h:97:14:   required from ‘constexpr decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) std::construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::jthread; _Args = {void (Test::*)(std::stop_token), Test*}; decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) = std::jthread*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/bits/alloc_traits.h:514:4:   required from ‘static constexpr void std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<_CharT >::construct(std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<_CharT >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::jthread; _Args = {void (Test::*)(std::stop_token), Test*}; _Tp = std::jthread; std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<_CharT >::allocator_type = std::allocatorstd::jthread]’

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind `&test` to `&Test::operator()`, then use [`std::placeholders::_1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to reserve a place for unbound `std::stop_token`:

```
struct Test {
  void operator()(std::stop_token token) {
    using namespace std::literals;
    while (!token.stop_requested()) {
      std::cout << "Working ...\n" << std::flush;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  auto my_thrd = std::make_shared<std::jthread>(
    std::bind(&Test::operator(), &test, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/6qsdxc8MT)

As @Nicol Bolas commented, we can also use C++20 [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) to do this, which is more lightweight and intuitive than `std::bind`:

```
auto my_thrd = std::make_shared<std::jthread>(
    std::bind_front(&Test::operator(), &test));
```

Comment: You should use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front). It's much less heavyweight.

Answer (score 2):

A simple, efficient solution is to use a lambda:

```cpp
auto my_thrd = std::make_shared<std::jthread>(
  [&test] (std::stop_token token) { test(token); });
```

and spare the extra includes and library facilities

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5effc53fb92b1409)

Answer (score 0):

`jthread` (or `thread`, for that matter) accepts any callable object. That includes anything with an `operator()`, like...`Test`.

The default is to pass by value; use `std::ref` to pass by reference, but note that you are on the hook for ensuring that the referenced object outlives the thread in that case.

So this is just:

```
auto my_thrd = std::make_shared<std::jthread>(test);
```

or (to pass by reference like your original code):

```
auto my_thrd = std::make_shared<std::jthread>(std::ref(test));
```